# Is there some sort of French saying for "a person's signature move"?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

I don't know why but I just feel like the French would have a saying for something like this, kind of like pièce de résistance but instead of the most prominent or best part of something, a signature or trademark move or aspect of a person's (especially an artist's) work.

Comment: I'm not exactly _sure_, but this seems to me somewhat related to either athletics or some sort of fiction material. For example, the brazilian gymnast _Daiane dos Santos_, has two "signature moves" - the _Dos Santos I_ and the _Dos Santos II_. From another context, Mario (from the Super Mario games) has a signature move on his Ground Pound attack, for example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from *marque de fabrique*, in the visual arts, in particular painting and film-making, you can use *la patte*.

Painters :

> - On admire notamment le décor conçu par René Allio, habituel partenaire de Planchon, où l’on retrouve dans le bariolage de la façade de Notre-Dame, un peu de **la patte de Rouault** dans Le *Fils Prodigue* en 1929, tout comme on retrouve dans le style de Petit, une trace de l’expressionnisme rugueux de Balanchine dans le même ballet.
> - Très rapidement, **la patte de Monet** va ressortir dans des falaises normandes, des paysages d'Argenteuil, jusqu'aux "Nymphéas".
> - Peintre à succès sous Louis XIII, tombé dans l'oubli dès sa mort, en 1652, Georges de La Tour n'a longtemps existé que dans quelques actes d'état civil, papiers notariés et autres inventaires après décès. Peintre sans tableaux, on a souvent attribué ses oeuvres à Vélasquez, Zurbaran, aux frères Le Nain, jusqu'à ce qu'un érudit allemand, Hermann Voss, le ressuscite en 1915 en rapprochant trois toiles mystérieuses, conservées dans des musées français et «donnant à voir, cadrés à mi-corps, des figures subtilement éclairées par la lumière d'une chandelle...» Il s'agissait du «Nouveau-né», du musée de Rennes, anonyme étiqueté Le Nain, qui avait déjà enthousiasmé Taine et même Maurice Denis. D'un «Reniement de saint Pierre» et d'un «Vieillard endormi», aujourd'hui baptisé «L'ange apparaissant à Saint Joseph», accrochés à Nantes et dans lequel Mérimée et Stendhal, un siècle plus tôt, avaient vu **la patte de Vélasquez**. Les deux tableaux nantais étaient signés G. de La Tour, mais personne n'était capable d'identifier l'auteur.

Film-makers :

> - Dans ces moments on retrouve **la patte de Melville** dans ses capacités assez personnelles de jouer sur la palette des couleurs : le travail sur les couleurs est remarquable, c’est un film bleu, ni noir et blanc, ni en couleurs !
> - On peut constater également ici que le fameux « réalisme poétique » qu’on attribue souvent à Carné et Prévert est entièrement né de **la patte de Renoir** qui filme comme il respire en jouant sur la lumière et la psychologie des personnages avec un art que n’aurait pas renié son père.
> - Pour Éric Neuhoff, journaliste au service Culture du Figaro, «on ne retrouve pas **la patte de Tarantino**» dans ce film [*Inglorious Basterds*] «dont on attendait peut-être trop».

When it comes to writers, *griffe* can be used.  It's very often used with  Voltaire whose polemical writings were often published under pseudonyms.

> - Il prend la plume pour rédiger un pamphlet intitulé *Lettres sur la Nouvelle Héloïse ou Aloïsia de Jean-Jacques Rousseau* attribué au marquis de Ximénès, alors hébergé à Ferney.  Personne bien sûr ne s'y trompe, tant est reconnaissable **la griffe de Voltaire**, lequel fustige avec la même vigueur le style de l'auteur, le contenu et la morale du livre, ou plutôt son immoralité.
> - Par ailleurs, la description des foules et du mouvement des masses, qui fait **la griffe de Zola**, confère à son œuvre une dimension épique et mythique : ce qui compte, c'est l'unicité, le collectif.
> - Les pièces de Dumas ont toutes dès la première scène la même intonation cassante et paradoxale, voix de tête et crête dressée; mais c'est sa marque de fabrique cela, son poinçon, **la griffe** au coin du tableau.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not familiar with "signature move" but according to your description, ***marque de fabrique*** (trademark, hallmark) used as a metaphor might be a possible translation.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/marque)

> P. métaph. *Toute cette histoire, d'un bout à l'autre (...) portait sa **marque de fabrique**, sa lourde griffe de bon ivrogne braillard* (Courteline, *Train 8 h 47*, 1888, 1repart., 5, p. 55). *Eux aussi ont un fonds commun, **une marque de fabrique** et c'est (...) cette manière stricte de dessiner, cette (...) alliance de la virtuosité aisée et du rendu photographique* (Estaunié, *Roman et Province*, 1942, p. 210).

Comment: +1, j'ai aussi parfois lu employé **sceau** mais je le trouve plus ampoulé.

Answer (score 11):

In Quebecois/French Canadian there is one expression that is told a lot for that;

´C’est sa marque de commerce.´

similar answer than jlliagre, just a bit different.

A example use; 
Les buts tardifs, la marque de commerce du Canadien (https://www.journaldemontreal.com/les-buts-tardifs-la-marque-de-commerce-du-canadien)

Answer (score 3):

When referring to a particular and singular work, you can say [**chef d'œuvre**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chef-d%E2%80%99%C5%93uvre), it is used in arts as in crafts. I think the English equivalent is masterpiece.

Referring to a move (but can be used out of this context), the fencing expression [**botte secrète**](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-l/3236-la-botte-secrete.html) can still be heard sometimes. Though as "secrète" (secrete) suggests it is supposed to surprise an opponent. So it can be a signature move but not really a trademark one...

Another expression coming to my mind is "**coup spécial**", from popular culture. I heard it almost only as the signature move of fighting games characters, or similar medias.

Answer (score 2):

Dépendamment de la formulation, on peut aussi employer l'adjectif « [caractéristique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caract%C3%A9ristique) » dans une relative visant le substantif du nom composé avec *signature* :

> *Chanel and her signature two-piece suit.* / Chanel et le tailleur (deux-pièces) **qui lui est si caractéristique.** ([Larousse en
> ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/signature/611793) anglais-français)